# Sharing data between php and javascript on same page

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to share data on same `.php` page. I receive some data on a page via POST method and I want to use it on javascript on that page during page load. But somehow javascript is showing the value `undefined`. What's the reason and how do I fix it?

```
<?php
    echo "<label id='origin' style='visibility:hidden;'>".$_POST["startStation"]."</label>";
?>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById('origin').value);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `label` does not have a `.value`. To access that data you need to use `.innerHTML`.

```
<?php echo "<label id='origin' style='visibility:hidden;'>".$_POST["startStation"]."</label>"; ?>
<script type="text/javascript"> alert(document.getElementById('origin').innerHTML); </script>
```